# Riemann's Zeta function

Tags: special-functions, riemann-zeta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Riemann Zeta Function and Analytic Continuation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/riemann-zeta-function-and-analytic-continuation)
>   [Calculating the Zeroes of the Riemann-Zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134362/calculating-the-zeroes-of-the-riemann-zeta-function)

It is stated that Riemann's Zeta function has zeros at negative even numbers.For example if -2 is directly  substituted, since the index is in the denominator each term will become a positive number.Then how does the value become zero

Comment: The series you have in mind is valid only for arguments whose real parts are greater than $1$. One then uses analytic continuation to have the zeta function be defined for the rest of the complex plane; this is one way to obtain values for the negative even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The definition $\zeta(s) = \sum{n^{-s}}$ is only valid for $\rm{Re}(s) \gt 1$.  Determination of its values for other arguments requires [analytic continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).  See: [Zeta regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization).